# Tate objects $\mathbb{Z}(n)$ in Hodge structures or mixed Hodge structures

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

The Tate object $\mathbb{Z}(n)$ is defined as the pure Hodge structures with lattice

$$\mathbb{Z}(n)=(2\pi i)^n\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{C}$$

and Hodge filtration induced by

$$[\mathbb{Z}(n)\otimes \mathbb{C}]^{-m,-m}=\mathbb{Z}(m)\otimes \mathbb{C}$$

and zeros in other degree. Why use the lattice $(2\pi i)^n\mathbb{Z}$? Why just use the lattice $\mathbb{Z}$ in the definition?

Comment: I guess to be in integral cohomology, if you look at $H^2(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{Z})$ lying in $H^2(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{C})$, if you integrate $dz\wedge d\overline{z}$ over $\mathbb{P}^1$ you don't get an integer. So you want to take $(2i\pi dz)\wedge \overline{(2i\pi dz)}$ as a basis for $H^{1,1}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{C})$ to have something in the image of $H^2(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: But if instead choose the lattice $\mathbb{Z}$ in the definition, I guess the two pure Hodge structures are isomorphic?

Comment: Yes, of course.